Motus et bouche close
En mon jeune âge, je crois  avoir eu l'occasion d'entendre, en particulier de la bouche d'un certain maître d'école, l'expression   « motus et bouche close ». Je n'arrive pas à la retrouver sur la Toile, et à sa place on a le fameux équivalent qui trône dans Tintin et Milou, c'est à dire  « Motus et bouche cousue » et dont l'origine remonterait au moins  au roman Eugénie Grandet (Balzac). Les ngram semblent confirmer l'inexistence totale dans le français de l'expression dont je crois me rappeler.

Est-ce que quelqu'un aurait souvenance de cette expression, peut-être comme déformation, régional ou autre, de la fameuse expression de Tintin et Milou,  et pourrait-il/elle donner des précisions la concernant ?
(Il pourrait s'agir d'une déformation personnelle due à  un enseignant ou issue d'un milieu culturel très limité en influence, ou de mon assimilation inconsciente de « bouche cousue » à bouche close », je ne peux que m'interroger sur les possibilités.)

Pourquoi un vote négatif ?

Personnellement je n'ai toujours entendu que motus et bouche cousue. Bouche cousue dont pour moi l'origine remonterait à George Dandin (Molière). Dans  l'acte I Lubin demande à George Dandin de garder le secret, il lui dit d'abord « motus¹ » (scène 1) et quelques lignes plus loin : « Adieu. Bouche cousue au moins. Gardez bien le secret, » (scène 2). Peut-être y a-t-il des occurrences antérieures au 17ᵉ siècle.
Personnellement j'avais bien sûr aussi déjà rencontré bouche close, aussi dans le sens de garder le silence, mais jamais à ce jour renforcé par motus. Mais il est évident qu'il est très facile, et logique de passer de bouche cousue à bouche close, sens semblable, et même nombre de syllabes selon la diction donc le rythme de la phrase est respecté.
D'un naturel curieux j'ai cherché pour voir si des gens seraient passé de l'un à l'autre, et j'ai trouvé au moins deux occurrences (merci internet) :

Dans un commentaire à la suite d'un article sur le site du magazine Le Point :


Là c'est motus et bouche close...


Dans un article de presse  malien :


Mais du côté de sa représentante, Armelle Deschamps, c’est motus et bouche close.

Une recherche un peu plus poussée m'a permis de trouver une occurrence plus littéraire de l'expression dans un roman de Xavier de Montépin, Simone et Marie (1883) :

Les affaires de l’administration, vois-tu ma vieille, ça ne te regarde pas... — Motus et bouche close !...

Et deux siècles auparavant La Fontaine employait motus et bouche close de façon disjointe dans ʀᴀɢᴏᴛɪɴ ᴏᴜ ʟᴇ ʀᴏᴍᴀɴ ᴄᴏᴍɪǫᴜᴇ (1684) :

ʙʟᴀɪꜱᴇ ʙᴏᴜᴠɪʟʟᴏɴ
Venez m'éclairer ; motus au moins, pour cause.
ʟᴀ ʀᴀɴᴄᴜɴᴇ
Oh !
ʙʟᴀɪꜱᴇ ʙᴏᴜᴠɪʟʟᴏɴ
Le voilà cloué, Dieu merci ! Bouche close.

Auparavant, dans son conte ʟᴀ ᴊᴜᴍᴇɴᴛ ᴅᴜ ᴄᴏᴍᴘᴇ̀ʀᴇ ᴘɪᴇʀʀᴇ (1762), La Fontaine avait employé l'expression synonyme :

De notre vie : encore un coup, motus,
Bouche cousue ; ouvre les yeux sans plus :

Tu peux donc très bien avoir entendu « motus et bouche close » auparavant.

¹ (1560; latinisation plaisante de mot → mot) Interjection pour demander à quelqu'un de garder le silence. (ᴅɪᴄᴛɪᴏɴɴᴀɪʀᴇ ʜɪꜱᴛᴏʀɪqᴜᴇ ᴇɴ ʟᴀɴɢᴜᴇ ꜰʀᴀɴçᴀɪꜱᴇ)

Je vais me contenter de votre recherche, elle me semble assez conclusive.

Motus et bouche close perd l'allitération sur le u dans motus et bouche cousue. C'est beaucoup moins joli.

@Frank         Indeed! En effet.
